# Example of a smooth function less than sin function

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Please help me to find an example of a smooth non-zero function $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(t)<\sin(t)$ for $t\neq n\pi$ and $f(n\pi)=0$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I want $f$ in an explicit form.
Thank you.

Comment: $f(t)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(t)$ (when $\sin(t)>0$).

Comment: You want $0<f(t)<\sin(t)$ but what if $\sin(t)$ is negative?

Comment: This is not possible since $\sin(t) \ngtr 0$.

Comment: Sorry. its my mistake. The correct question is $f$ is not zero everywhere.

Comment: Then as @Surb said, $f(t) = \frac{1}{2}\sin(t)$ for $\sin(t)\geq 0$ and $f(t) = 2\sin(t)$ for $\sin(t) < 0$.

Comment: @FrancescoCarzaniga This function is not smooth.

Comment: @Janik I read continuous instead of smooth, my bad!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take something like
$$ \frac{\sin{x}}{1+a\sin{x}} $$
for some $0<a<1$. This is smooth since it is a nonsingular combination of smooth functions, and $1+a\sin{x}$ is larger than $1$ when $\sin{x}>0$ and smaller than $1$ when $\sin{x}<0$. Hence it is always smaller than $\sin{x}$. And of course it has the same zeros as $\sin{x}$.